# Exclude all dot underscore files from rsync

Tags: regular-expression, rsync

How can I use `rsync -av` but exclude all files starting with dot underscore (`._example.txt`) and also ignore `.DS_Store` files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `--exclude="<filePattern>"`

```
rsync -av --exclude="._*" --exclude=".DS_Store" <source> <destination>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `--exclude='._*'` would make `rsync` ignore all files and directories with dot-underscore at the start of their names. With `--exclude='.DS_Store'` you would ignore the other type of file.

Answer (score 1):

To have multiple exclude rules without cluttering your command-line with several `--exclude` options, you can instead use the `-F` option and a `.rsync-filter` file listing the patterns to exclude.

> ```
> -F     The -F option is a shorthand for adding two --filter rules to your command.
>        The first time it is used is a shorthand for this rule:
>
>          --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter'
>
>        This tells rsync to look for per-directory .rsync-filter files that have
>        been sprinkled through the hierarchy  and  use  their rules to filter the
>        files in the transfer.
> ```

Here is an example of a `.rsync-filter` file in the root of the folder to backup:

```
- /temp
- /lost+found

# Windows thumbnails
-p Thumbs.db

# MS Office temporary files
-p ~$*

# common Mac junk
-p .TemporaryItems
-p .DS_Store
-p ._*
```

The `p` modifier after the `-` means "perishable", which will make rsync also delete these excluded files on the destination.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude files and directories that match `._*` and `.DS_Store` then either of the earlier answers is sufficient:

```
rsync -av --exclude='._*' --exclude='.DS_Store' src dst
```

On the other hand, to answer your question exactly as asked, this snippet will exclude files that match your criteria while still including directories that match `_*` and `.DS_Store`:

```
rsync -av --include '.DS_Store/' --include '._*/' --exclude '.DS_Store' --exclude '._*' src dst
```

Worked example

```
# Set up the example directory tree
mkdir -p src/a/.DS_Store src/a/._example.dir dst
touch src/.DS_Store src/._example.txt src/a/.DS_Store/keep src/a/._example.dir/keep src/item src/a/another

# Show what we have
find src -type f

    src/.DS_Store
    src/._example.txt
    src/a/.DS_Store/keep
    src/a/._example.dir/keep
    src/a/another
    src/item

# Copy it. Omit matching files but keep the directories
rsync -av --include '.DS_Store/' --include '._*/' --exclude '.DS_Store' --exclude '._*' src/ dst

    sending incremental file list
    ./
    item
    a/
    a/another
    a/.DS_Store/
    a/.DS_Store/keep
    a/._example.dir/
    a/._example.dir/keep

# Tidy up
rm -rf src dst
```